# What's wrong in my JS function?

Tags: javascript, function

I am optimizing a Java code to JS, **but runs on Nashorn and do not own debug option**. The input is `val = "JPG ou PNG"` and the output is `"JPG ou PNG"`. Why does this happen? I need the output to be `"jpg/png"`

Function

```
function process(val) {
    var cleaned = val.replaceAll("[•×\\tª°▪º⊗　ﬁ ²●˚~ĩ`ũ]", "").trim().toLowerCase();
    var out = [];
    if (cleaned.contains("ou")) {
        out = cleaned.split("ou");
    }
    else if (cleaned.contains("/")) {
        out = cleaned.split("/");
    }
    else {
        return cleaned;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < out.length; i++) {
        out[i] = out[i].trim();
    }
    return join(out, "/");
}
```

Comment: What are `replaceAll` and `contains`? [String.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype) has no such methods

Comment: these functions don't exist in JS?

Comment: Neither does `join`, when its used like that. Here is your code in javascript http://jsfiddle.net/s5wng5g8/1

Comment: @PedroEstrada `join` exist

Comment: you need to include `jquery`

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring) SO post there is no `contains` function.

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim its not used in that manner though, thats what i meant to say, the correct way is `array.join(separator)`

Comment: @Daniela Marques de Morais Yes, they're missing in JS. You have to use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) methods instead

Comment: @ozil: jQuery has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three of your functions don't exist in javascript:

1. `replaceAll(searchValue, newValue)` in javascript is `replace(searchValue, newValue)`
2. `contains(searchValue)` in javascript is `indexOf(searchValue) > -1`
3. `join(array, separator)` in javascript is `array.join(separator)`

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s5wng5g8/1/%20%22DEMO)**

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
function process(val) {
    var cleaned = val.replace("[•×\\tª°▪º⊗　ﬁ ²●˚~ĩ`ũ]", "").trim().toLowerCase();
    var out = [];
    if (cleaned.indexOf("ou") >= 0) {
        out = cleaned.split("ou");
    }
    else if (cleaned.indexOf("/") >= 0) {
        out = cleaned.split("/");
    }
    else {
        return cleaned;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < out.length; i++) {
        out[i] = out[i].trim();
    }
    return join(out, "/");
}
```

Your logic was right, but strings in Javascript don't have 'replaceAll' and 'contains', so I replaced them with 'replace' and 'indexOf(x) >= 0'.

Also, you mentioned you don't have the option to debug in your environment, yet the function you provided is pretty standalone. This means you could easily copy it into another environment to test it in isolation.

For example, I was able to wrap this code in a HTML file then open it in my web browser (I had to implement my own 'join').

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function join(val, divider) {
    var out = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
        if(out.length > 0) out += divider;
        out += val[i];
    }
    return out;
}

function process(val) {
    var cleaned = val.replace("[•×\\tª°▪º⊗　ﬁ ²●˚~ĩ`ũ]", "").trim().toLowerCase();
    var out = [];
    if (cleaned.indexOf("ou") >= 0) {
        out = cleaned.split("ou");
    }
    else if (cleaned.indexOf("/") >= 0) {
        out = cleaned.split("/");
    }
    else {
        return cleaned;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < out.length; i++) {
        out[i] = out[i].trim();
    }
    return join(out, "/");
}

var inval = "JPG ou PNG";
var outval = process(inval);
console.log(inval + " => " + outval);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I verified it works by opening up the console and seeing the output "JPG ou PNG => jpg/png".